# SQL TD EKM Azure Key Vault - can't restore encrypted database

Tags: sql-server, encryption-asymmetric, tde, azure-keyvault

Using the steps detailed in [this MS article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198405(v=sql.110).aspx) I have successfully enabled SQL TDE using Azure as an EKM. To ensure that I would be able to decrypt the data on another server in the event of a DR scenario, I first uploaded my own asymmetric key (in the form of a password-protected pfx file) into Key Vault as per the [steps in this MS article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/).

I'm now trying to test DR, where I'll have to restore a backup of the encrypted DB onto another SQL server, and whatever I try I can't get it to work. I'm sure it's something painfully obvious to those familiar with SQL encryption, but it's got me stumped!

I've read various articles such as [this one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2914662) explaining how to convert then import the pfx certificate using PVKConverter.exe.  Initially, trying to import the converted pfx threw the error *Msg 15581, Level 16, State 1, Line 1. Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.* so I created one in the master DB using

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MySecurePassword'
```

This didn't get me any further as the backup still wouldn't restore.

Comparing the two servers, the obvious difference is that the master DB holds my Key Vault-linked Asymmetric key in the encrypted Server A (`SELECT * FROM sys.asymmetric_keys`) and a certificate in Server B (`SELECT * FROM sys.certificates`).  I understand that I can't export an asymmetric key from SQL (hence I used the existing pfx in Key Vault) but I just can't work out how to use/import that pfx in Server B to allow me to restore the encrypted DB backup from Server A.  Whenever I attempt to create an asymmetric key in the master DB from my pfx file using the below:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY MY_ASYMMETRIC_KEY
FROM FILE = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.CORIC\MSSQL\DATA\\MyPFXFile.pfx'
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD 'C0mplexP@ssw0rd'
```

I get the error: *Msg 15208, Level 16, State 43, Line 18
The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.*

The full SQL used to enable TDE on Server A is below, in the hope that this will provide the insight needed to spot the problem:

```
USE master;
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
sp_configure 'EKM provider enabled', 1 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO

CREATE CRYPTOGRAPHIC PROVIDER AzureKeyVault_EKM_Prov 
FROM FILE = 'C:\Program Files\SQL Server Connector for Microsoft Azure Key Vault\Microsoft.AzureKeyVaultService.EKM.dll';
GO

CREATE CREDENTIAL sysadmin_ekm_cred 
    WITH IDENTITY = 'mykeyvault', 
    SECRET = '12345678123412341234123456789abcfedcba98-fedc-fedc-fedc-fedcba987654'
FOR CRYPTOGRAPHIC PROVIDER AzureKeyVault_EKM_Prov

ALTER LOGIN [LOCALMACHINE\AdminUser]
ADD CREDENTIAL sysadmin_ekm_cred;

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY KEY_VAULT_ASYMMETRIC
FROM PROVIDER [AzureKeyVault_EKM_Prov]
WITH PROVIDER_KEY_NAME = 'mykeyvaultkeyname',
CREATION_DISPOSITION = OPEN_EXISTING

CREATE CREDENTIAL Azure_EKM_TDE_cred 
    WITH IDENTITY = 'mykeyvault', 
    SECRET = '12345678123412341234123456789abcfedcba98-fedc-fedc-fedc-fedcba987654'
FOR CRYPTOGRAPHIC PROVIDER AzureKeyVault_EKM_Prov

CREATE LOGIN TDE_Login 
FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY KEY_VAULT_ASYMMETRIC

ALTER LOGIN TDE_Login 
ADD CREDENTIAL Azure_EKM_TDE_cred ;

USE MyDatabase;

CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY 
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER ASYMMETRIC KEY KEY_VAULT_ASYMMETRIC

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET ENCRYPTION ON ;
GO
```